# sos.dll extension loading in a Kernel dump or Live kernel debug session

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, clr, windbg

Is it possible to load sos.dll into a debuggers extension chain when in a Kernel debug session or looking at a kernel memory dump?

Specifically I want to use livekd to look at a virtual dump of my live system. 
Livekd is a sysinternals tool that allows me to look at kernel structures of a Windows system with out booting into debug mode. It take a virtual dump of the system and present it as a dump file.
Then I want to target a .NET process. To dump out the .NET data structures it would be ideal to be able to load in the sos.dll or sosex.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load SOS as an extension.

No, it won't be helpful: a kernel dump contains all **physical** memory of the machine. SOS (or other .NET extensions) needs all **virtual** memory of the process.

To debug a .NET process, you attach to the process (press F6 in WinDbg, make sure you choose the right bitness). No need to do kernel debugging.